# Why does my house plant have brown leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, indoors

Why does my house plant have brown leaves scattered all around? I water it when it's dry, it gets enough sunshine. It's growing fine as the vines are getting longer. But the brown leaves won't stop coming. Maybe I shouldn't be doing this, but I cut the brown leaves off and they come right back. What am I doing wrong?

There are no rocks at the bottom and no fertilizer. I do water it a lot. It's a hanging plant as well. I use water from my kitchen faucet, as I do with all my other plants, and I have no issues with them at all.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Hi! I added the text from your comment on stormy's answer. It's good information, and since comments don't always last, and can be hard to find, I thought it might be helpful. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Sue Sure. I have no problem with that and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagnostic indicators are the brown spots indicative of a virus/fungus/bacteria.  This is usually caused by overwatering or poor drainage or both.  Verify that you:

- water the plant when the top inch of soil is dry
- water enough that water runs out the bottom of the pot
- the plant is not sitting in water that is the tray or any sub irrigation in the pot

This plant is a variety of pothos which are vigorous vines. They can outgrow the problem. To reduce or control it I recommend:

- increase light levels
- decrease the amount of water
- consider taking the plant out of it's pot an looking at the roots. Soft and black indicates root rot, firm and white is new growth, yellowish or brown firm roots are older growth.  If there is any rot cut back the root system and repot

Answer (score 2):

I would just repot in fresh bagged soil and QUIT watering with tap water. Use distilled water (unless you are on a well system). I'd also split this plant in the near future and 2 plants out of it.  This plant is so dang tough the only thing that makes it brown on tips, edges...is the salt in tap water or being root bound.  What are you fertilizing with, how often, is there just soil in that pot or did you put gravel/rocks at the bottom of the soil?  That would make a big difference and put more urgency towards changing things.  Your plant is a vigorous plant but not happy at all.  Could be a too small pot, too much fertilizer, tap water.  Pothos is majorly tough and if healthy can be one of the most beautiful house plants.  Let us know what you've been doing, this should be easy to suss out.

Comment: No rocks at the bottom and no fertiizer. I do water it alot. Its a hanging plant as well. I use water from my kitchen faucet, as I do with all my other plants, and I have no issues with them at all

Comment: I concur about changing the soil with a new bag of potting soil. I don't particularly agree or disagree with the other things people have said, at this point, though. I recommend a red clay or ceramic pot, too.