# Dark spots scattered on my fig

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

I have asked this question on here before, but these brown spots are different from the ones that I have asked about in my other question. These brown spots are very dark and are scattered, and they're appearing on the newer foliages. I would put a link to the question I asked about the other brown spots but I don't know how to do it. Why is this happening? I know why it's happening from my previous question but I don't know about these brown spots; these spots are different.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your watering schedule like? Have you been over-watering this plant? (I have not seen your other question).

If anything, over-watering is my first bet. If not, then look into how much sun light the plant has been getting, and whether the exposure is direct or indirect (for best results, it has to be bright, indirect light) and whether it was somehow suddenly exposed to frost.

The plant loves humidity, but is quite sensitive to over watering. It should be allowed to go dry or nearly dry between watering.

It may be pests, but if your other house plants are healthy and the plant was healthy up to this point, then I would focus on the aforementioned ideas first.

Not that you asked, but this appears to be a Fiddle Leaf Fig or a variant thereof.

Comment: By the way, is this the other question you are referring to? http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/29780/why-does-my-house-plant-have-brown-leaves

Comment: No, thats my other plant

Comment: The other question has the title fiddle fig in it

Comment: You can look up your own profile and find the questions you have asked as well as the answers you have given.

Comment: Oh ok, thats good to know.

Comment: What is special here is that only ONE leaf has these spots.  That is indicative of chemical burns...or physical harm.  Another possibility is that you moved it over by those sliding glass doors (?) and this leaf was touching the glass when the sun was magnified or the glass got so cold it froze a bit of your leaf.  This is a Fiddle Leaf, not a fig, fig.  Great indoor plant.  Yours needs more light more consistently.  This next spring think about repotting with new potting soil and a clay pot 2" larger in diameter.

Comment: You are right about the possibility of course! I would explore all the options, watering, sun exposure, other damage possibilities, and finally disease.

Comment: @stormy I think it could've been when the sum was magnified because the area where I put it at (glass) ita gets extremely hot and it get direct sun. I dont put it by the sun everyday; more like every 2-3 days. Is this bad? Should it be everyday? I also keep a humidifier in the area of the plant.